# Python implement a preorder method of a binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree

Why can't this python program run correctly. I would like to build a binary tree and then traverse it in pre-order. When I call the `PreOrder` method, it returns nothing.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None, left=None, right=None):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.data = data

class BTree:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root

    def CreateTree(self, root):
        self.root.data = raw_input("Enter data,'*' means empty: ")
        if self.root.data == '*':
            return
        self.root.left = Node()
        self.root.right = Node()
        self.CreateTree(self.root.left)
        self.CreateTree(self.root.right)

    def PreOrder(self, root):
        if self.root != None:
            if self.root.data != '*':
                print self.root.data,
                PreOrder(self, self.root.left)
                PreOrder(self, self.root.right)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Node()
    bt = BTree(t)
    bt.CreateTree(t)
    bt.PreOrder(t)
```

Answer (score 3):

`PreOrder` is a method of the class `BTree`, you might want to change the recursive calls, like so:

```
def PreOrder(self):
    if self.root != None:
        if self.root.data != '*':
            print self.root.data,
            self.root.left.PreOrder()
            self.root.right.PreOrder()
```

You also don't need to pass `root` to `CreateTree`, if you are only using `self.root` which you saved in `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

I you look at your `CreateTree` method, you will see, that you never use `root` and therefore `self.root.data` will always be `*`. If you fix that, your code has more problems, all related to `self` and scopes. You might want to check [this](http://diveintopython.net/object_oriented_framework/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Your `CreateTree` method does not mention the parameter `root` at all. This method always operate on `self.root`.

Something like this may work:

```
def CreateTree(self, current_node):
    current_node.data = raw_input("Enter data,'*' means empty: ")
    if current_node.data == '*':
        return
    current_node.left = Node()
    current_node.right = Node()
    self.CreateTree(current_node.left)
    self.CreateTree(current_node.right)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting  `self.root.data = '*'` in the `CreateTree` function by doing 
this `self.root.data = raw_input("Enter data,'*' means empty: ")`. And to terminate the input prompt you have to enter `'*'` in the end. So last value that your `self.root.data` has is '*'.

Try this

```
    print self.root.data
    root.data = raw_input("Enter data,'*' means empty: ")
    print self.root.data
    if root.data == '*':
        return
```

and this

```
    def CreateTree(self,root):
        print self.root.data
        root.data = raw_input("Enter data,'*' means empty: ")
        print self.root.data
        if root.data == '*':
            return
        self.root.left = Node()
        self.root.right = Node()
        self.CreateTree(self.root.left)
        self.CreateTree(self.root.right)

    def PreOrder(self, root):
        print root
        print self.root
        print self.root.data
        if self.root != None:
            if self.root.data != '*':
                print self.root.data,
                PreOrder(self, self.root.left)
                PreOrder(self, self.root.right)
            else:
                print 'what the hell'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Node(10,Node(),Node())
    print t.data
    bt = BTree(t)
    bt.CreateTree(t)
    bt.PreOrder(t)
```

to know where it went wrong.